# Memory leaks in a STL list

Tags: c++, list, memory-leaks, stl, valgrind

I am writing a class which contains a member, more precisely the native container `std::list`, and a method. The method retrieves a set of points (`Point2i`, from OpenCV) and adds them to the list. My algorithm works properly, but it produces memory leaks according to Valgrind reports. Although I delete all the elements of the list using member functions such as `clear` after having processed my list (as well as in the destructor of the class), Valgrind tells me that all the elements of the list have not be freed, whereas I was assuming that it was the role of `clear`. Sorry if this question sounds stupid, but is it really normal ?

Here are the relevant portions of my code, first the header :

```
class Detector : public Method
{
public:
    Detector();
    ~Detector();

protected:
    int detectFeatures();
    list<Point2i> centers;
};
```

Then the code, properly said :

```
int Detector::detectFeatures() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < im.rows ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < im.cols ; j++) {
            bool undetected = true;
            for (int y = max(0, i - radius) ; y <= min(im.rows - 1, i + radius) && undetected ; y++) {
                for (int x = max(0, j - radius) ; x <= min(im.cols - 1, j + radius) && undetected ; x++) {
                    if (im.at<Vec4f>(y, x)[3] > 0.9) {
                        centers.push_back(Point2i(j, i));
                        undetected = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
    centers.clear();
}

Detector::~Detector() {
    centers.clear(); // I also tried this
}
```

Finally, here is the Valgrind output of the program (the list contains 103 510 elements) :

```
==7182== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7182==     in use at exit: 2,484,240 bytes in 103,510 blocks
==7182==   total heap usage: 103,543 allocs, 33 frees, 41,812,122 bytes allocated
==7182== 
==7182== 2,484,240 bytes in 103,510 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==7182==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7182==    by 0x4054C8: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<cv::Point_<int> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:92)
==7182==    by 0x4053E5: std::_List_base<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >::_M_get_node() (stl_list.h:327)
==7182==    by 0x4052AC: std::_List_node<cv::Point_<int> >* std::list<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >::_M_create_node<cv::Point_<int> >(cv::Point_<int>&&) (stl_list.h:491)
==7182==    by 0x40510D: void std::list<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >::_M_insert<cv::Point_<int> >(std::_List_iterator<cv::Point_<int> >, cv::Point_<int>&&) (stl_list.h:1523)
==7182==    by 0x404E5A: std::list<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >::push_back(cv::Point_<int>&&) (stl_list.h:993)
==7182==    by 0x403D58: Detector::detectFeatures() (detector.cpp:72)
==7182==    by 0x401C0D: main (main.cpp:35)
==7182== 
==7182== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7182==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7182==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7182==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7182==    still reachable: 2,484,240 bytes in 103,510 blocks
==7182==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

And this cannot be an OpenCV problem in my code : I tried `std::pair` instead of `Point2i` but I got the same problem. Whatever the type, the elements are not really deallocated when the program ends. The same if I use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::list`, where the data is this time "definitely lost".

Should I do something more than calling `clear` or `erase` on each element of the list ? Thanks in advance for your comments and answers !

__

**EDIT** : There were some elements I didn't precise above, and possibly the most important one : `Detector` inherits from `Method` and this is an object of class `Method` that I instanciate in my program.

```
class Method {
public:
    Method();
    ~Method();
    virtual void detectFeatures() = 0;
};
```

Instanciation :

```
Method* m = new Detector();
m->detectFeatures();
// ...
delete m;
```

As `centers` is a member of `Detector`, it won't be destroyed if the destructor of `Method` is not `virtual`, which was not the case in the code I showed you. Now that `~Method()` is actually virtual, there are no longer memory leaks. So the problem has nothing related with containers, it was rather an inheritance problem. Thank you so much !

Comment: There is a problem in code you are not showing. Create a small complete C++ program that reproduces this issue. For example, try to reproduce the problem with just the code you have shown above.

Comment: `list` is going to take care of its contents when it goes out of scope, regardless of calling `clear`. So as jxh said, your problem is elsewhere. Perhaps you aren't deallocating a `Detector` object, thus it's members are leaked? Or may that's inside of some other object that's leaked... etc.

Comment: does Method have a virtual destructor?

Comment: I have to agree with the others, because I do not see any memory being declared on the heap that you are showing. It is somewhere else that either new or malloc is being used. Also another thing I would do is to replace any raw heap pointers with either std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr. This way when they go out of scope their destructors will handle the clean up of any memory allocation.

Comment: I predict you have a global variable of type `Detector`. Valgrind report is being generated before that variable is destroyed. Alternatively, you allocate an instance of `Detector` on the heap, and leak it.

Comment: @RichardHodges : Thanks for your intuition ! Finally, the problem had nothing related with std::list. It was that `Detector` is inheriting from `Method`, and my list is defined in `Detector`. Besides, I instanciate an object of class Method like this : `Method *m = new Detector()` and then, I call the destructor of `Method`. As the destructor of `Method` was not virtual, `~Detector()` and `centers.clear()` was never invoked. Hence the memory leaks. Thanks again, and thanks everyone !

Comment: @Mukyu common enough mistakes for a beginner. (almost) Always make base class destructors virtual, never use new and delete. use make_unique and make_shared to make smart pointers. Happy coding! :)

Comment: You have not yet explained how your `detectFeatures()` method bypassed the `clear()` call.